# Setting button image also ends up adding the word "button" to image; how to fix

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

So I made some assets in sketch and have successfully imported them into Xcode.  When I attempt to give a button the image of one of these assets, Xcode does just that, but it also ends up adding the word "button" next to my image (seen in picture).  I have a feeling my settings in the inspector could be the culprit, however playing around with them has yielded no victory.

Would you be able to recommend any solution?
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbw3R.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Button title "Button" from the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want button title and background image then assign your image into Background field which is below Image field and if you don't want button title then assign that image in Image field and remove title `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

See the picture. By default it will take the title as `Button`. delete it. This will resolve your issue.[image: Delete the underline word]